# Find your OWN crash location to retrieve inventory

Tags: no-mans-sky

I encountered a glitch where after taking off I got stuck inside a cave system and my ship got destroyed.

I respawned in the systems space station with a message saying 'Return to location of crash to retrieve ship inventory', but the problem is there is no marker/waypoint to the exact location! All I know is which planet I was on, nothing else!

Has this happened to anyone before? How can I find my inventory? My ship was carrying a lot of the rare materials =(

Comment: My friend had it once where he loaded his game and it told him he'd died. After a while, it returned his "lost" inventory to him without him doing anything. How long has it been since this happened?

Comment: It literally just happened - i tried reloading my saves but nothing is there. My previous save was overwritten because I entered and exited my ship before attempting to reload :\

Comment: That is unfortunate. In my friend's case, I think his missing cargo appeared right next to him, unless it returned it automatically. Try waiting a bit (he ranted to me for half an hour before it resolved itself) and see if you have any luck. I tried searching for a solution but other people have run into a bug where their death marker never shows up, it seems, and I haven't seen a solution yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems this is a glitch that can fix itself. I logged out last night and logged back in earlier today and the 'Grave' marker was on my radar. Flew over to the location and all my inventory was there.